# Multi-Access to file - Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, file

I've made a dynamic PDF file creator and every time I'll click a button it generate a new PDF file (removing the older) using data on a database.

My problem is that if I try to create a new PDF and the file is opened in any client the program can't edit the file.

Is there a way to create something like "sessions" that permit every user to edit the file at the same time?

P.S. Sorry for the bad english, I've tryed my best, I hope that someone edit my question in a proper way.

Answer (score 1):

This is just vague solution to do

Step 1: Each time user requests for data, create a new PDF with time stamp in PDF Name, that way it stands unique.

Step 2: Try to delete old files as soon as you create new file. 
Or
Step 2: Use a purge job to delete old files.

Comment: It's not what I was talking about, I've seen some pages on the web that after the address of the file (ex: "site.com/file.pdf) they add something like a HTML Get (ex: "file.pdf?requestId=qwerty123").

Comment: Can you explain little more about your problem ?

Comment: I've made a Dynamic PDF file that is created every time I click a button in a Windows Application that use a Web Service. When I click the button it opens a browser with the PDF page. My problem is that if I'll try to open the file from the directory and then (while the file is loaded) I'll launch the application there's an error because it can't delete the file. I've seen in some web sites that is used some form of session for this purpose and I was asking about this method... I don't know how it's called and I can't find it on the web

Comment: Query string can be used to get required information by developer. We can't use sessions to close the browser/file. Instead you can alert user to close opened PDF on click of button. If my solution is not clear paste your code here.

Comment: It's not what I'm talking about, sorry